# Pass through folder with any specific pattern

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have a batch script that would only copy pdf file, based on the user inputted code. As soon as they hit enter it will look for a folder that has same filename with the inputted code.. then if exist it will copy the pdf inside..

Now I'm having a problem because in one sub-folder, it's file name doesn't have standard filename.

Like for ex : sometimes its filename is `UV DATA` others is `UV-DATA` , `UV`

example folder structure storage for the pdf file :

> ```
> server
> '----22050-022
>      '----Folder1
>                22050-022-DATA.pdf
> ```

example folder destination :

> ```
> server2
> '----Folder
>      '----22050-022
>           '----UV DATA
>                '----DOCUMENTS
> ```

The `UV DATA` folder is the only one is changing..
How can I set only only `UV` and second word is any specific pattern?

Sample XCopy if it is a static code and make default file name is `UV DATA`:

```
set /p code=Input Control Number:

xcopy "%MySetPath%\Folder\%code%\%code%-DATA.pdf" "%MySetDestination%\Folder1\%code%\UV DATA\DOCUMENTS\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
```

I only tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
set /p code=Input Control Number:

xcopy "%MySetPath%\Folder\%code%\%code%-DATA.pdf" "%MySetDestination%\Folder1\%code%\UV*.*\DOCUMENTS\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
```

Comment: I'd Suggest using for loop/s to retrieve the name of the file with `%%~nI`, test the value for the target string with a findstring subroutine, then, if the result shows the target string to be present, perform the command.

Comment: @T3RR0R can you show me how can I achieve that?

Comment: will the destination folder always be exactly the same as the PDF name? Or can the destination folder be different? In other words any PDF file with `UV` in the name should be copied to a folder with `UV` in it?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard `UV ` is not the pdf file it's a subfolder filename which i need to pass through to copy the PDF file inside of it..

Comment: ok, please do me a favour, edit the question and show me example pdf file and example destination path.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard See my edit.. i just need to put the copied pdf in folder destination.. the problem is `UV DATA` is sometimes changing to `UV-DATA` and `UV` ....

Comment: ok, let me have a look at your structure quick and will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Change current directory to HOMEDRIVE.
cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%" || (
    >&2 echo Failed to change directory to "%HOMEDRIVE%"
    exit /b 1
)

rem Get the control number i.e. 22050-022.
set /p "code=Input Control Number: " || exit /b 0

rem Set initial source path and destination path here.
@rem Note: destination path without trailing "\UV*\DOCUMENTS".
set "source=%HOMEPATH%\%code%\Folder1\%code%-DATA.pdf"
set "destination=%HOMEPATH%\Folder\%code%"

rem Check initial source path.
if not exist "%source%" (
    >&2 echo Initial source path "%source%" not exist.
    exit /b 1
)

rem Check initial destination path.
if not exist "%destination%" (
    >&2 echo Initial destination path "%destination%" not exist.
    exit /b 1
)

rem Get "%%destination%%\UV*\DOCUMENTS\" path.
(
    set "destination="

    for /d %%A in ("%destination%\UV*") do if not defined destination (
        @rem Force an echo on line break.
        if exist "%%~A\DOCUMENTS\" set "destination=%%~A\DOCUMENTS\"
    )

    if not defined destination (
        >&2 echo Failed to get destination from "%destination%".
        exit /b 1
    )
)

rem Copy file from source to destination if file date is newer.
xcopy /d /y "%source%" "%destination%"
exit /b 0
```

This will try to find the destination path with
`UV*` in the path as specified in the OP and
comments as to my understanding.

Change directory to `%HOMEDRIVE%` else a path
starting with `%HOMEPATH%` can be invalid if
the the current directory is on another drive.
If you use a drive which mirrors the `%HOMEPATH%`
then you can disable the change of directory to
remain on that drive.

The destination path is resolved to the
`DOCUMENTS` folder, else the `destination`
variable will be detected as undefined.

Checks are done to ensure initial source
and destination paths exist.

Since only 1 file is being copied, using
`xcopy` arguments that apply for 1 file.
Check to see if I am correct.

To understand what the code is doing, set
the line `@echo off` to `@echo on` to test.

Comment: `Failed to get destination`... it doesn't get through UV folder.. it stops only in %code% folder....

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks for the effort... :)

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards in **folders** are not supported in operations like `xcopy`

This solution using `FOR /F` is sort of hacky, but definitely works:

```
@echo off
set /p "code=Input Control Number:"
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%MySetDestination%\Folder1\%code%\UV*"') (
xcopy "%MySetPath%\Folder\%code%\%code%-DATA.pdf" "%MySetDestination%\Folder1\%code%\UV-%%a\DOCUMENTS\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H
)
```

This will copy the file to all folders in the format `UV<ANYTHING HERE>`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the script, since all answers don't seem to work. You can use `FOR /D` to loop in folders, but in a batch file the 'd' disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. You need to setup the source and the destination paths below to ensure you have the best level to search, but as `dir /s` is used, you can go to the lowest level of both source and destination paths:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p "code=Input Control Number: "
set "source=%HOMEPATH%\%code%"
set "destination=%HOMEPATH%\folder"
if "%code%" == "" echo Please input a valid Control number & goto start 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s "%source%" ^| findstr /i "%code%" ^| findstr /i "pdf"') do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad "%destination%" ^| findstr /i "%code%" ^| findstr /i "UV" ^| findstr /i "Documents"') do (
    echo "%%a"
    echo xcopy "%%~i" "%%~a" "/D /E /C /I /Y /H
)
```

Comment: what paths did you give the source and destination?

Comment: for source `%HOMEPATH%\%code%\Folder1\%code%-DATA.pdf` and for destination `%HOMEPATH%\Folder\%code%\UV DATA\DOCUMENTS` ... i tried it first locally..but it doesn't work

Comment: can you edit your answer and try to put the path inside `for /` and don't set it as variable...

Comment: See edit please. Do not put the full paths as you did.